# Reorder columns in a 2d matrix to maximize the count of all repeated subarrays across all rows

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, matrices

I have a matrix (input):

| -- | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | AA | BB | CC |
| r2 | CC | RR | BB |
| r3 | EE | DD | FF |
| r4 | KK | DD | EE |
| r5 | DD | GG | KK |
| r6 | PP | QQ | KK |

1. Let's call each matrix cell a `namespace`. If two rows begin from the same namespace, then such a namespace is called a `reused` namespace. A reused namespace does not need to be a prefix. In the example below, namespaces `AA`, `BB` are reused twice because a better arrangement does not exist (prefix namespace `HH` has been reused 4 times):

- `[EE, AA, BB, CC, ...]`
- `[HH, AA, BB, RR, ...]`
- `[HH, ...]` x(4)

2. The amount of reused namespaces is a score calculated for the whole matrix. If `N` rows share a common prefix of length `K`, then `(N - 1) * K` is the amount of reused namespaces.
3. Let's define a **score** for a matrix as an amount of reused namespaces for all matrix rows.
4. It is allowed to reorder elements in each row. Other operations are disallowed.
5. Let's define an **arrangement** as a configuration of the matrix where the elements in each row are reordered.
6. Constraints: the largest matrix I have is 1067 rows by 19 columns.

I need to find an arrangement that maximizes the matrix score. An easier explanation is I need to sort all row elements in a way that maximizes the score. The problem is that greedy solution (sort each row by counter across the matrix) will not work for all cases.

**Example 1**:

- `[AA, CC, DD, ...]`
- `[AA, CC, DD, ...]` (score: +3, the whole prefix is reused)
- `[BB, CC, KK, ...]` (`CC`, `KK` namespaces were reused, even though prefix namespaces differ (`BB` and `PP`)); (score +1 for `CC`)
- `[PP, CC, KK, ...]` (score: +2; `CC`, `KK` where reused)

**Example 2** (possible arrangement for the example matrix above; calculated by the code below):

| -- | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | BB | CC | AA |
| r2 | BB (score +1) | CC (score +1) | RR |
| r3 | EE | DD | FF |
| r4 | KK | DD | EE |
| r5 | KK (score +1) | DD (score +1) | GG |
| r6 | KK (score +1) | PP | QQ |

I implemented a naive version in Python.

First, I defined a ranker returning a score for a matrix arrangement. I used a prefix tree to get the count of reused prefixes (it is a simplification of what I need):

```python
class Trie:
    def __init__(self, matrix: list[list[str]]):
        self.root = {}
        self.score = 0

        for row in matrix:
            self.add(row)

    def add(self, row: list[str]):
        root = self.root
        for word in row:
            if (child := root.get(word)) is not None:
                if word:  # handle padding empty strings
                    self.score += 1
            else:
                child = {}
                root[word] = child

            root = child
```

Second, I get all possible permutations across all columns and rows:

```python
def generate_permutations(matrix: list[list[str]]):
    num_cols = len(matrix[0])
    col_indices = [*range(num_cols)]

    col_permutations = [*permutations(col_indices)]
    row_permutations = product(col_permutations, repeat=len(matrix))

    for row_permutation in row_permutations:
        permuted_matrix = []
        for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
            permuted_row = [row[col_idx] for col_idx in row_permutation[i]]
            permuted_matrix.append(permuted_row)
        yield permuted_matrix
```

Finally, I find the best arrangement based on the ranker score:

```python
def namespace_sort(matrix: list[list[str]]):
    best_arrangement = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
    best_arrangement_score = Trie(best_arrangement).score

    for arrangement in generate_permutations(matrix):
        score = Trie(arrangement).score
        if score > best_arrangement_score:
            best_arrangement_score = score
            best_arrangement = arrangement

    return best_arrangement
```

This algorithm will never work for hundreds of rows and columns.

Is there a known optimal algorithm I can use to solve the problem? Otherwise how can I optimize the solution?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  I see a long post, but it does not contain any questions.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require that your post articulate a specific, concrete question.

Comment: How do you define "the amount of reused namespaces"?  What do you mean by "an arrangement"?  What is the input to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?  Are you given a matrix, and you want to re-order it?  Or are we allowed to fill in the matrix in any way we want?  What are the constraints on what matrix we're allowed to produce or what kinds of re-orderings are allowed?  I don't understand what the examples are trying to indicate or what the notation in the examples is.

Comment: Rather than using "EDIT:" and appending more information, we would prefer that you revise the question so it reads well and is understandable for people who encounter this page for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.

Comment: Please add the score for **Example 1**&**2**.

Comment: @greybeard, I added a sample. Please keep in mind that I do not have a perfect scoring implementation, and these examples show what I have to achieve.

Comment: The title mentions `Reorder columns`, the procedure description `all possible permutations across all columns and rows` (which I don't quite see in `generate_permutations()`), and there's a definition of *arrangement* in `5.`. The two examples contradict each other: in **Example 1**, CC & KK are mentioned to increase score, different **c1** value notwithstanding. In **Example 2**, the DD in r4, c2 is not annotated to increase score - which I think a better fit with `If two rows begin from the same …`. Without this constraint, how would reordering matrix columns change score?

Comment: (With an improved specification and working code, this question may do better over at [CODE REVIEW@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: Could you review and verify greybeard's answer? Does it answer your question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking `two rows` in `1.` to mean *two consecutive rows*, it would seem to suffice to establish counts of each namespace in either row and permute the subsequent row such that common ones appear in the same column.
I would not call this *Reorder columns in a 2d matrix*.
I have no idea how *repeated subarrays* fit into the picture.

```
def namespace_align(matrix: list[list[str]]):
    ''' Return a matrix with same values in subsequent rows
        column aligned where possible.
    '''
    reference = matrix[0][:]
    ref_counts = Counter(reference)
    arrangement = [reference]
    #
    for row in matrix[1:]:
        counts = Counter(row)
        fresh = (counts - ref_counts).elements()
        arranged = []
        for namespace in reference:
            if 0 < counts[namespace]:
                arranged.append(namespace)
                counts[namespace] -= 1
            else:
                arranged.append(next(fresh))
        arrangement.append(arranged)
        reference, ref_counts = arranged, counts
    #
    return arrangement
```